# Live noise-filter on line-in

Tags: windows, audio, noise-cancelling

I'm running the following setup:

- Xbox 360 is hooked up to my (PC) screen via HDMI/DVI converter.
- Because the Xbox has no dedicated sound output, except for optical S/PIDF, I'm also using the AV/RCA output, namely just the audio, which is connected to an old stereo, which is then connected to my PCs line-in.

I'm now experiencing a *some* of noise. I'm using one of the standard "Realtek High Definition Audio" cards, which doesn't seem to offer this kind of functionality. Is there a software that will playback audio right off a device while running filters on it? It doesn't have to create a device on its own, I just want to listen to it.

Here's a sample: http://puu.sh/1x2MA/79c38b25abfe51058fd664971c8e4ab7

Comment: Sounds like you have a [ground loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_loop_(electricity)), filters (as you are looking for) are not your answer.

Comment: Related/more info: [Laptops without ground loop noise](http://superuser.com/questions/168796/laptops-without-ground-loop-noise)

Comment: I don't know what that sample is supposed to be, but the link is not working.

Comment: Updated the link, forgot I wiped my puush account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Winamp using the line-in feature and a DSP plugin.  I've done something similar when streaming to ShoutCast before.

If the default line-in plugin doesn't play nice with your sound card you can try this alternative one which has some more options:  http://home.hccnet.nl/th.v.d.gronde/dev/lineinWA2/index.html